# Wordpress wp_redirect issue

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am having some trouble with wp_redirect in my plugin.

Here is my code:

```
    public function update($year, $edit_id, $column1, $column2) {

    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'tableName_'.$year;

    $Column1 = intval($column1);

    $Column2 = intval($column2);

    $NewTotal = ($Column1 + $Column2);

    $wpdb->update($table_name, array('Column1' => $Column1, 'Column2' => $Column2, 'Column3' => $NewTotal), array('month_id' => $edit_id));

    wp_redirect(get_option('siteurl').'/wp-admin/admin.php?page=myplugin');

    exit();

}
```

When I execute:

I get the following error:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/.../public_html/wp-admin/includes/template.php:1953) in /home/.../public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1171

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: clean any whitespace, tabs, hidden characters or empty lines in your PHP files before and after the php tags ( opening and closing )

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add below code in your `functions.php`

```
function app_output_buffer() {
    ob_start();
} // soi_output_buffer
add_action('init', 'app_output_buffer');
```